# type of iterator c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I'm trying to write my own sort function that can sort vector container.

I'm hoping to call it in the following manner:

this:sort(arr.begin() , arr.end() - 1)

**arr.end() - 1 - because arr.end() returns the next element, actually not element, returns iterator to end**.

So i want to call my function with iterator on any type.I tried to run this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector> 
using namespace std;

template<typename T1> 
void func(vector<T1>::iterator it) {
    cout << "\n" << *it; 
}

int main() {
    vector<int> arr(10);

    for(int i = 0;i < 10;++i)
        arr[i] = i+1;

    func<int>(arr.begin()); 
}
```

But compiler says:

```
main.cpp:10:23: error: variable or field ‘func’ declared void  void func(vector<T1>::iterator it)
                              main.cpp:10:32: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘it’  void func(vector<T1>::iterator it)
                                 main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: main.cpp:26:5: error: ‘func’ was not declared in this scope
     func<int>(arr.begin());
     func main.cpp:26:10: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     func<int>(arr.begin());
```

Please explain me my mistake.Thanks

Comment: You may wish to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: *Never* include anything from `bits` directory - do `#include <vector>` instead!

Comment: Well , it doesn't affect.

Comment: Привіт! Try to put `typename` right after `(`

Comment: Привіт , можеш пояснити як , будь ласка??

Comment: You're also not returning from the main, given that the return type is int, so you should do something like: return 0;

Comment: @Welshboy - `main` (and only it) is exempt from this

Comment: This is an English only site, please write only in English here...

Comment: Note that `typename std::vector<T>::iterator` is non deducible (you would have to call `foo<myType>(..)`). Simpler to use `template <typename It> void foo(It it)`.(You might then use `std::iterator_traits` to check category).

Comment: _arr.end() - 1 - because arr.end() returns the next element, actually not element, returns iterator to end_ what?

Comment: `template<typename Iter>
void func(Iter it)`would be much easier.

Comment: You are right, but i want to write mergesort using buffer array with specific type.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler doesn't know that iterator is a type inside `vector<T1>`

```
template<typename T1> void func(typename vector<T1>::iterator it) {
    cout << "\n" << *it; }
```

> Inside a template, some constructs have semantics which may differ
>   from one instantiation to another. Such a construct depends on the
>   template parameters.

You should write `typename` for such dependent types.

Comment: Oh , thank you  a lot.And one question in which cases we should write typename ??

Comment: That's what this answer is lacking... In case of [dependent names](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).